# Elasticsearch with PHP connection not working

Tags: elasticsearch, php-8.1

I am using `Elasticsearch 8.1`. It is running on port `9200`. When I execute from POSTMAN,

```
https://localhost:9200/learn/_search
```

with Authorization: `Type: Basic Auth` and username & password, I can see the result.

But now I want to implement this using PHP. I have installed `"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^8.0"` in my composer. This is the code I have tried.

```
use Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

$hosts = [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '9200',
    'scheme' => 'https',
    'user' => 'elastic',
    'pass' => 'LisRrIul9oMKh2deJkMv'
];

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->build();


$params = [
    'index' => 'learn',
];

$results = $client->search($params);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
```

I am getting

```
`[Thu Mar 31 22:07:09 2022] 127.0.0.1:44396 [500]: GET / - Uncaught Elastic\Elasticsearch\Exception\ClientResponseException: 404 Not Found: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
 in /home/user/Projects/Els/my-apps/esphpsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Response/Elasticsearch.php:65
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/Projects/Els/my-apps/esphpsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Client.php(168): Elastic\Elasticsearch\Response\Elasticsearch->setResponse()
#1 /home/user/Projects/Els/my-apps/esphpsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Traits/ClientEndpointsTrait.php(1521): Elastic\Elasticsearch\Client->sendRequest()
#2 /home/user/Projects/Els/my-apps/esphpsearch/index.php(24): Elastic\Elasticsearch\Client->search()
#3 {main}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setBasicAuthentication('elastic', 'LisRrIul9oMKh2deJkMv')
    ->setCABundle('/etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt')
    ->setHosts(['https://localhost:9200'])
    ->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'learn',
];

$results = $client->search($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with your `ClientBuilder` call, since the response indicates that at least the port setting did not work (as it contains `localhost Port 80`).

Try passing the parameters in one URL string:

```
$hosts = ['https://elastic:LisRrIul9oMKh2deJkMv@localhost:9200'];
```

To then get the indices, you can use `cat` instead of  `search`:

```
$indices = $client->cat()->indices($params);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach too.

Comment: Is the response exactly the same? Is your elasticsearch positively running on the same machine as the webserver?

Comment: Yes I am running locally. Elastic search is running in 9200 port. And php in 8000. I am getting result using curl and also in postman